# Consulta anilhada usando mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Bom dia, tenho a necessidade de realizar uma consulta alterando os dados do objeto no mongoose mas não tenho obtido exito em encontrar os metodos interno que fazem isto e tanto $facet quanto as subpipeline não satisfazem o que busco.

Tenho um objeto da seguinte forma:

```
{
    Campo1,
    campo2,
    campo3:{
        objetoid,
        arrays:[{
           id_outhertable,
        }
 }
```

preciso popular os objetos dentro do array com o objeto real em outra tabela, isto com seus respectivos campos em uma outra 'coluna', e como se não bastasse, serão 2 consultas anilhadas, sendo que a ultima usa informação do campo1 e id_outhertable.

Não sei se fui claro, tentei ser o mais claro possível caso contrario desde já peço desculpa.

Comment: blz.. post um exemplo da collection ai.. pelo que entendi vc quer alterar o arrays com a busca principal no campo1

Comment: Este é um exemplo da colection, claro que omiti dados e os tipos eu subentendi que vc sacaria, como os dict e array.